# change the size of SVG to to 45 percent of its original size without using zoom

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to make this svg to look 45 percent of its actual size so I zoomed it like this:

```css
.ring {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.ring-circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
    transition: stroke 0.60s ease, stroke-dashoffset 0.60s ease;
  
}

.guy {
    zoom: 0.45;
}
```

```html
<div class="guy">
                <svg class="ring" height="200" width="200">
                    <circle stroke-width="8" stroke="#8a8184" fill="transparent" r="84" cx="100" cy="100"/>
                    <circle class="ring-circle" stroke-width="17" stroke="#ff8000" fill="transparent" r="84" cx="100" cy="100"/> 
                  
                    <foreignObject height="162" width="162" x="19" y="19">
                        <img
                        src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18320/profile/profile-512.jpg?3"
                        style="border-radius: 50%; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
                        />
                    </foreignObject>
                </svg>
            </div>
```

I tried to change the width and height of the SVG itself instead of using zoom property in CSS but that way I only could change the viewport I think...

Comment: How about transform: scale(0.45)

Comment: instead of zooming or scaling the svg I want a proper solution to resize the svg...

Comment: why isn't scaling a "proper" solution? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `viewBox` and set the SVG's size by the container div:

```css
.ring {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;   
}

.size-100-pct {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.size-45-pct {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="size-100-pct">
  <svg class="ring" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <circle stroke-width="8" stroke="#8a8184" fill="transparent" r="84" cx="100" cy="100"/>
    <circle class="ring-circle" stroke-width="17" stroke="#ff8000" fill="transparent" r="84" cx="100" cy="100"/> 
    <foreignObject height="162" width="162" x="19" y="19">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18320/profile/profile-512.jpg?3" style="border-radius: 50%; width: 100%; height: 100%" />
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="size-45-pct">
  <svg class="ring" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <circle stroke-width="8" stroke="#8a8184" fill="transparent" r="84" cx="100" cy="100"/>
    <circle class="ring-circle" stroke-width="17" stroke="#ff8000" fill="transparent" r="84" cx="100" cy="100"/> 
    <foreignObject height="162" width="162" x="19" y="19">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18320/profile/profile-512.jpg?3" style="border-radius: 50%; width: 100%; height: 100%" />
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</div>
```